# Change progress bar color in blueimp jQueryUI file uploader

Tags: jquery-ui, file-upload, progress-bar, blueimp

Is it possible to change the colour of the upload bar of bluimp's jQueryUI file uploader?
The default is an orange and I want to change it to light-blue but in the docs there is no documentation for the progress bar styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** it is possible to change the color of the upload bar of bluimp's jQueryUI file uploader in order to achieve the user required/custom colors we have to modify the progressbar.gif image which you can find in the img folder.

Check out your css for the path of the progress.gif image
It will look like

```
   .progress-animated .bar {
  background: url(../img/progressbar.gif) !important;
  filter: none;
}
```

If it doesn't work for you do let me know. I will help you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just created a static gif image of the colour I want but it would be great if they can include more colours of the same animated gif